# How to set environment variable for sshd

Tags: environment-variables, openssh, openssl

I have Ubuntu server 14.04 on a server with openssl version 1.0.1f and openssh version 6.6.

In my `openssl.cnf` I have `subjectAltName=${ENV::ALTNAME}` so that I can set `subjectAltName` on the commandline when creating certificates.

When I try to start my ssh daemon manually it fails with:

```
Auto configuration failed
140031266363040:error:0E065068:configuration file routines:STR_COPY:variable has no value:conf_def.c:618:line 224
```

The problem seems to come from openssl failing to start because environment variable `ALTNAME` is unset and hence sshd can't run.

So my question is how can I set the environment variable ALTNAME to some initial value before the sshd service is started?

Comment: Try to add in `/etc/environment` which contains a definiton of the `$PATH` variable

Comment: @AzkerM I tried that but it seems to be loaded after the sshd service is started.

Comment: You lost me there.. So you've added it already but didn't do a service restart? and now it work?? Am I getting it right?>

Comment: I added it to /etc/environment and restarted the machine but the ssh server wasn't running after startup. I verified that the variable ALTNAME had a value and found that I could start the server manually when it was set which is why I came to the conclusion that the ssh service is trying to start before /etc/environment is read. 

Now I have removed ALTNAME from /etc/environment since it didn't work as intended.